# execSync - How to see ongoing script execution

Tags: javascript, child-process

I am using `execSync` to execute a shell script within a javascript script

```
const { execSync } = require('child_process');
const shell = (cmd) => execSync(cmd, { encoding: 'utf8' });
shell('node jest');
```

When I run `jest` from my terminal, I see each step in the console as the script is ongoing.

When I run `shell(script)`, I only see the whole results at the end of the script.

#### Question

What should I do to output in live the execution of a script using `execSync`?

Comment: It's **sync** so your program does nothing but wait until it finishes, and while it waits it can't do anything else, so you can't output the stdout or stderr. You should probably use the regular `exec` and do some digging on how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found the proper method.

> child_process.exec() is "synchronously asynchronous", meaning although the .exec is asynchronous, it waits for the child process to end and tries to return all the buffered data at once
>
> child_process.spawn() returns an object with stdout and stderr stream

Hence I opted to use `spawn` and created

```
const shellAsync = (cmd) => {
  const script = spawn(cmd);

  script.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`${data}`);
  });

  script.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.error(`${data}`);
  });

  script.on('close', (code) => {
    console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
  });
};
```